# UIwebview automatically shrinks even after assigning height from code

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

I have a UIwebview inside a UIscrollview. I have made the View controller size to freedom to allow scrollview.

I have given the height of scrollview = 1000 and webview = 200 in storyboard.
Now, in code i am adjusting the height of webview o basis of the content recieved.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

The log states `size: 280.000000, 676.000000`

But after scrolling the webview automatically resizes to the size given in storyboard.
Do i need to disable something / or am i missing something?

Comment: are you loading html content or url in webview

Comment: Can you comment `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` in your code and see if it works?

Comment: @Amar :  no it stills shrinks but with scroll bar. so now i have two scroll bars, one of the scroll view and another of the 'shrinked' webview.!!! :(

Comment: You also need to increase the scroll view content size in which the webview is a subview. Also check if you have applied any autosizing to webview from the storyboard. That can also cause issues related to frame.

Comment: @Amar the scrollview is already 1000 . and the size of webview after loading comes to 676. Still it resizes again to 330...!!!

Comment: From the docs: `Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the code in

```
webViewDidStartLoad:
```

Also check you code where you have implemented scroll to see if you are setting web view frame or size during scroll action, if you have implemented any.

Comment: If i write the code in webViewDidStartLoad, it gives me the size i had assigned in storyboard.
size: 280.000000, 330.000000 - in didstartload
size: 280.000000, 676.000000 - in didfinishedload

in short on srolling it goes back to height 330

Comment: did you check if you are reassigning values to scrollview size anywhere else that sets it back to the old size again.? Try setting a breakpoint at the places where you assign the size to scrollview and run the program..

Comment: webViewDidFinishLoad is the only method where i am assigning the frame to webview.. and still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = [[your_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
    webView.frame = frame;
}
```

Hope it will helps you....

Comment: Th problem is not with assigning the height... I have checked the log. It assignes, but only for a short moment or unless i scroll the view. Then it again resizes to 330 which i had given in storyboard

Comment: check whether you are changing the webview frame in somewhere of your coding